# Translating future statements

Tags: present-continuous, future-perfect, double-possessives

I've translated the next sentences:

1. A brother of my friend's will have finished university by the summer and he is looking forward to teaching at school.
2. Tomorrow he'll be working all the day and we'll go to pool because I think he'll have finished all his work by that time.

These two sentences belong to the same exercise. And can't be get from the context. So I would like to know if I use "double possessive" correctly. And could I use "We're going to pool" as it is arrangement? Or as we aren't sure about his success at doing his work and we haven't arranged our meeting at a concrete time I should use simple time?

Comment: Your *a brother of my friend's* is credible, but relatively unlikely. Most native speakers would use *my friend's brother* in contexts like that. But you seem to be asking several things at once here, with no evidence that you've done any prior research (so at least we'd know what you *do* understand, and can thus concentrate on the things you still find confusing).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I've made someresearch butstill don't understand the difference between "double possessive" and "possesssive case". And waht about the second question?

Comment: "We're going" is OK, because we often use the present continuous to describe plans, but "to pool" is not correct, because *pool* is a specific countable noun, so it has to be "we're going to **the** pool."  We don't use an article for activities, but *pool* is a place, not an activity.

Comment: @Anthony: "possessive case" just refers to words which are "inflected" (modified in form/sound) to indicate possession (or some other type of association). This includes both the Saxon genitive *(John = **John's**)* and possessive pronouns *(me = **my, mine**, he / him = **his**, they = **their, theirs**, etc.)* In constructions like [*an X of John's, an X of mine/his/etc.*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50588/) the last word *can* be a "possessive" form - but it doesn't need to be, because ***of*** already carries the required sense. Follow that link for more details.

Comment: @stangdon: It would be possible to say *I'm going **to pool** tonight* in contexts where the reference is to *playing in a pool hall* - as an *organised/regular activity*, similar to *John's not here right now - he's out **at football** this afternoon*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Fair enough.  I was thinking of *pool* as *swimming pool*, not "playing billiards".

Comment: @stangdon: I didn't mean to "undermine" your earlier assertion (which I've upvoted, because in the general case it's a useful perspective for learners). I just thought it might interest some people here to be aware of and consider closely-related usages that don't necessarily seem to follow the same general principles. Apropos which arguably the US/UK split over *to go to (**the**) hospital* is relevant, I dunno.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - No worries!  It's always good to be reminded of alternate interpretations.  And yes, I think *hospital* is the one really significant difference between US and UK English vis-a-vis what counts as an activity vs. a place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I'm grateful for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *A brother of my friend's* points out that my friend has, at least, two brothers. I would say: "One of my friend's brothers", it sounds more natural to me than "a brother of my friend's". If my friend has only one brother, it's better to say *my friends's brother.*
   [More information on double possessives](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/double-possessives)
2. It's better to say *to graduate from the university* instead of *to finish university*.
3. *To THE pool,* as Stangdon said.
   *We are going* is correct since the Present Continuous is used for arrangements.

Comment: Please note that we say: "He graduated from Harvard University" (with the zero article since Harvard University is a proper noun which does not require the definite article. Compare with "the University of Hawaii"). In sentences like this: "When students graduate from univesity, they are awarded licence", we also use the zero article since "to graduate from university" means 'to be a graduate'. We use "the" when we speak about a specific university or college.

Comment: You've read my minds) I had wanted to make up a new topic on this issue before I got your response. But it is already written. I appreciate your help.